# What is Jest's equivalent of Mocha's root-level hooks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to write tests for my Node.js backend application with Jest.
The backend has `mongodb` implementations via mongoose.

I need to have a global hook, in which I can connect to the database before running *all* tests in all test files.

In Mocha, I can do it easily as [documented here](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks):

> You may also pick any file and add “root”-level hooks. For example, add `beforeEach()` outside of all `describe()` blocks. This will cause the callback to `beforeEach()` to run before any test case, regardless of the file it lives in (this is because Mocha has an implied `describe()` block, called the “root suite”).

So I could, for example, create a `testHelper.js` file and write:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
// ./test/testHelper.js
before((done) => {
  const mongoURI = `${process.env.DB_MONGO_URI}/testdb`;
  mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true});
  mongoose.connection
    .once('open', done)
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.warn(error);
      done();
    });
});

after(() => {
  mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

The above will run before and after all tests in all test files.

How can I do the same above with jest?

Answer (score 2):

Jest API has [`beforeAll` and `afterAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#one-time-setup)  for this purpose.

It shares the concept of  top-level implied `describe()` block with Mocha, other blocks don't necessarily have to be placed inside `describe`, including `beforeAll` and `afterAll`.

Notice that due to that Jest tests run concurrently, `beforeAll` and `afterAll` will affect only current test environment, i.e. tests defined in the same file.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean to have a root `beforeAll` and `afterAll` that will run before and after all tests in all test files. Is this possible?

Comment: You can move them to a common module (testHelper) and import it in every test file or use global* config options, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string .